# Is it "a grammar mistake" or "a grammatical mistake"

Tags: grammar

It seems to me that when we say "a grammatical mistake" it means a mistake that is grammatical in nature (something that is grammatical can't be a mistake, right?!), so i'd say "a grammar mistake" is correct. However, I've seen a lot of controversy about it. which one is correct?

thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, grammar mistake or mistake in grammar. Some utterance or written phrasing or phrase or sentence is or not grammatical.

Comment: In other Germanic languages, you would write either "grammar-mistake" with or without the hyphen, or "grammatical mistake", but in English the noun adjuncts are usually separate words, which causes a lot of confusion, and this seems to be the core of the question here.

Comment: There are two definitions of *grammatical* per [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grammatical). According to the first definition, *grammatical mistake* makes perfect sense. But according to the second definition, the phrase is nonsensical. That's why I always say *ungrammatical*. But *mistake in grammar* is always understood too.

Comment: What do dictionaries say 'grammatical' means? The use of the attributive is usually also acceptable.

Answer (score 7):

Either is fine. In your examples, *grammatical* is an adjective and *grammar* is an attributive noun, which is a noun functioning as an adjective (also called a [noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct)).

From the Wikipedia article:

> It is a trait of natural language that there is often more than one way to say something. Any logically valid option will usually find some currency in natural usage. Thus "erythrocyte maturation" and "erythrocytic maturation" can both be heard, the first using a noun adjunct and the second using an adjectival inflection.

Answer (score 3):

According to COCA(https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/), Ngram(https://books.google.com/ngrams) and English Web 2020(https://sketchengine.eu/), both "grammar mistake" and "grammatical mistake" are correct.                  [image][image][image][image]

Answer (score 1):

I think your assumed definition of "grammatical" may be wrong. It is generally (and in this example) used with the meaning "relating to grammar".

So a **"grammatical mistake"** is a **mistake relating to grammar**.

In the same way, you can say something is "gramatically correct", or "gramatically incorrect" i.e. - correct with respect to grammar, or incorrect with respect to grammar.

The other meaning of grammatical, which I think is rather misleading and perhaps used too often on this forum is essentially "correct with respect to grammar". So this second form of "grammatical" means "grammatically correct".

**"Grammar mistake"** sounds to me a little clunky and odd, as it is generally used as a noun, but I wouldn't say it's downright wrong. I would personally favour **"grammatical mistake"**.

Comment: You see the same with "logical", which can mean pertaining to logic or can mean compliant with the rules of logic.

Answer (score 0):

Mistakes related to grammar are grammatical mistakes. The term " grammar mistake " is non-standard and used by uneducated people .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Both phrases have their place. 
“Grammar mistake” has some legitimate uses and may even be better than “grammatical error” in some cases.  
For instance, when a young student makes a very basic writing mistake, it may be more communicative for a teacher to say, “you made a grammar mistake here.”  While “grammatical error” is more often used for errors made by more advanced (or more _educated_?) writers, that doesn’t mean people who use “grammar mistake” are “uneducated” as you imply in your answer.  That might be considered an insult to those teachers (et al) who use the phrase effectively.